# How to generate a JSON file from a tflite file

Tags: android, json, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

I'm working on a mobile app which uses machine learning, and I managed to create a .tflite file with the model. However, I also need the JSON file to be able to implement the model into the app. I have two questions about this:

1. Is there a way to generate a JSON file from a tflite file after training? If so, how?
2. I also have an h5 version of the model, which I can use to create a JSON file. However, I need to convert this h5 file back into .tflite so that it can fit on an app. If I do this conversion, will the JSON file I made earlier still be compatible with the tflite file?

Thank you!

Comment: For the app are you using Tensorflow JS?

Comment: No, just Tensorflow java

Answer (score 1):

Flatbuffers compiler with the tflite.schema and file_name.tflite, will fetch you the file_name.json.

Eg : ./../flatc -t --strict-json --defaults-json tflite.schema -- filename.tflite

Flatbuffers : https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Is there any way to convert JSON to TFlite file?